# Is that possible to intercept declarates new attributes in python class?

Tags: python, class, attributes, declaration, magic-function

Creating new attributes in class instace we can intercept with `__setattr__` magic function.
`self.new_attribute = "hi!"`

But if I want to intercept creation of class attributes?

```
class NewClass():
     new_attribute = "hi!"
```

Is that possible? If so, how? Metaclasses?

P.S. It's possible with using `inspect` inside the class (such as `DeclareAttribute("new_attribute", "hi!")` with using getframe inside), but in this case I'm losing possibility of code navigation to this name.

Comment: Metaclasses seem like the best way to me.

Comment: If you want to modify how attributes you define in the class scope are created, you need to override `__new__()` on the metaclass.  If you want to control dynamically added class attributes, use `__setattr__()` on the metaclass.  (In Python 3, you could also override `__prepare__()` on the metaclass to change the dictionary type, which can also change the way in which attributes are set.)